# Making Menu programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make menu from the code. I want to know what is the programmatic equivalent of **android:showAsAction**. I know we can have it in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [setShowAsActionFlags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsActionFlags%28int%29) with one of the constants you want.

See **constants** section for [constants you can pass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS).

Comment: Thankyou.This was exactly what I was looking for. Have low reputation so can't vote up. Anyways thanks again.

Comment: No effect of showasaction method when i added programatically. @Madushan